# Best practice for deleting large amounts of data from Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to delete a few hundred thousand entries from a large table. I'm using PostgreSQL. From what I've read, a popular safe approach is to copy the "to be deleted" primary keys of the entries in my table to a temporary one and delete them with a join.

Can someone explain to me the benefits of doing it this way? And is there a different way you would do it?

I've looked at [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/delete-join) link. It highlights the technique but, to me, it just seems like the same approach as running a script to delete all entries in a table given the primary key.

Comment: The queries in that link would not work in PostgreSQL in the first place.

Comment: One important question is: what is the condition to delete the rows? Can it be written in SQL? One big `DELETE` is bound to be faster than hundred thousand small ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that PostgreSQL's delete syntax lets you "join" in the same way an update statement does with the FROM clause or the way another SQL implementation may let you run "DELETE X FROM t1 AS X JOIN t2 AS Y USING(row_id);", for example.

You can work with a WHERE clause in your DELETE statement from 1 table, so if your deletion condition depends on records in other tables then you might see a benefit in first compiling a list of primary key values which fit the condition (using a SELECT query with as many JOINs as you want) and then passing your list of key values into a simple WHERE clause of your DELETE query, as a complicated row-dependent subquery in the WHERE clause may be slower than this.

For server memory/resource efficiency it also probably makes sense to split up the querying/row-finding operations (the SELECT of the key values) from the storage-modification operation (the DELETE), and I've heard it recommended too to run the DELETE portion in batches (say 100000 rows at a time) to have a lighter footprint on memory and logs, but I am uncertain whether that's wise or unnecessary in PostgreSQL specifically or if it varies between implementations.

A general theme in processing large data-sets is that consecutive smaller steps or chunks often perform better than big complex single actions which struggle to lift too much at once.

If you have a simple deletion condition that would fit directly into a WHERE clause on your target table, and you don't have millions of rows, the simplest "DELETE FROM _ WHERE _" query could very likely serve you fine.